# TypeError: Incorrect padding (b64decode Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, encoding, base64

Trying to scrape one site (Russian language, cyrillic) and save all content in csv, but get error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/kr/PycharmProjects/education_py/credit_parser.py", line 30, in 
>       base64.b64decode(listing_title[0].encode('utf-8')),
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
>       raise TypeError(msg)
>   TypeError: Incorrect padding

My code

```
# coding: utf8
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
import csv
import base64

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17"
}

csvfile = open('credit-listing.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

i = 1

while i < 2:
    url = requests.get("http://credit-board.ru/index.php?page=search&sCategory=116&iPage={}".format(i), headers=headers)
    page_html = fromstring(url.content)
    all_listings = page_html.xpath('//*[@id="listing-card-list"]/li')
    listings_list = []
    for listing in all_listings:
        listing_urls = listing.xpath('./div/div/div/div/a/@href')[0]
        listing_request = requests.get(listing_urls)
        listing_html = fromstring(listing_request.content)
        listing_title = listing_html.xpath('//*[@id="item-content"]/h1/strong/text()')
        listing_text = listing_html.xpath('//*[@id="description"]/p[1]/text()')
        listing_meta = listing_html.xpath('//*[@id="custom_fields"]/div/div/text()')
        listings_list.append([listing_title, listing_text, listing_meta])
        writer.writerow([
            base64.b64decode(listing_title[0].encode('utf-8')),
            base64.b64decode(listing_text[0].encode('utf-8')),
            base64.b64decode(listing_meta[0].encode('utf-8'))
        ])
    i+=1
    print i
```

Comment: Some lines got less than 4 character length and you sure `incoming data isn't encrypted !`

Comment: How i can fix it? I can't change content on site.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `b64encode` instead of  `b64decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
try:
    if divmod(len(field),4)[1] != 0:
        field += "="*(4-divmod(len(field),4)[1])
    #decode field here
except Exception,e: print e
```

Field =  base64 encoding items.

Encrypted not `base64.encoding`, encode first before decoding and never decode other tools (field.encode('utf-8') is wrong) all base64 encoding items got url_safe character pattern.

Comment: What is - field ? And what line exactly i need to write this code?